# Mongo db alphabetical sorting in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, coffeescript, alphabetical

I have a collection of users, and I insert them into a select box to be viewable by the user. I am wanting to sort this collection by the users name and then pass that on.

I am currently grabbing the roomName and then returning that roomName.active_users. It populates the select box but then doesn't sort them.

```
Template.room_active_users.getActiveUsers = (roomName) ->
    users = Rooms.findOne({room_name: roomName}).active_users
```

I have tried doing

```
users = Rooms.findOne({room_name: roomName}).active_users.profile.name
```

but that doesn't work.

Currently this is what is inside the collection when I console.log(users):

```
[Object, null, Object]          // This says that there are 2 users in the room
   0: Object
       _id: "ryYnj48Gcgd25fwHm"
       profile:
           avatar_url:
           bio:
           blog:
           .
           .
           .
           login:
           name: Jerry
   1: null
   2: Object
       _id: "hg4mxeTjDxFdTpJJe"
       profile:
           avatar_url:
           bio:
           blog:
           .
           .
           .
           login:
           name: Bob
```

I am trying to find a way to access the users' names and just sort them that way but you can't call

```
.active_users.profile.name
```

It gives this error:

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I figured I would have to write some type of sort function to do this, but all the examples I've searched for have turned out to not work, and none are specific enough to fit my case.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try the aggregation framework instead

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and collect in the database or do it in code. Really the db is gonna be better at this sort of thing and there's not much of a reason to pull back all those fields when you only need one. But if you want to do it in code, I'd use [lodash's pluck](http://lodash.com/docs#pluck):

```
# load the users collection into lodash so you can do multiple operations chained
# compact removes nulls
# pluck gets only a certain key from the collection of objects 
# value returns the value from the chain
#
_(Rooms.findOne({room_name: roomName})).compact().pluck('name').value()
```

Is findOne really not asynch? Seems like it should be...

It also looks like findOne accepts a [projection parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-projection), in which case you'd need to just pass that in like so:

```
Rooms.findOne({room_name: roomName}, {'name':1})
```